# Per Application Menu Bar (like Unity) in Gnome

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, appmenu

I know Unity is based on Gnome and has the application-specific menu bar at the top (which can be set in the settings). I am running Ubuntu Gnome and was wondering if it was possible to get that in pure Gnome perhaps using a shell extension or modifying some values using dConf.